# Custom HTTP Header with webservice call

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I need to make a webservice call in C# and with every request i need to send a custom HTTP header. How do i do this.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that implements [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx).   In the BeforeSendRequest method, add your custom header to the outgoing message.  It might look something like this:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,  System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMessage;
    object httpRequestMessageObject;

    if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out httpRequestMessageObject))
    {
        httpRequestMessage = httpRequestMessageObject as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpRequestMessage.Headers[USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER]))
        {
            httpRequestMessage.Headers[USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER] = this.m_userAgent;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER, this.m_userAgent);
        request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then create an endpoint behavior that applies the message inspector to the client runtime.  You could apply the behavior as an attributes, or using a behavior extension element.

Here is a great [example](http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2007/04/27/wcf-building-an-http-user-agent-message-inspector.aspx) of how to add an HTTP user-agent header to all request messages.  I am using this in a few of my clients.  You could undoubtedly do something similar for just about any header.  You can also do the same on the service side by implementing the [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx).

Is this what you had in mind?